# how to create responsive div components?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

Can anyone provide me a video link or a way to create 10 responsive `div`s dynamicly to show products or anything inside them like [this website](http://www.yummly.com/).

As you can see the there are 35 `div`s and they have a picture along with text. Now I know how to get the data from database but I would like to know how can I create  (i.e 10 `div`s) which are created dynamicly and responsive?

thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: try to use Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap grid system to display your div responsively : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
Look at the example Stacked-to-horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to use a good grid system. You can find a really good responsive grid system here:

https://github.com/vahidseo/vgrid

the min version is under 1kb. Using it is really easy. Just follow the link and instructions.